# Display empty string in xaxis with jqplot

Tags: jquery, jqplot, linechart

I using jqplot for my line chart, I have 2 field in data [date, int],my json data here:

```
[{"12/15/2013": "10"},{"12/16/2013": "0"}, {"12/22/2013": "10"},{"12/29/2013": "0"},{"12/30/2013": "10"}]
```

- In this data, days 15, 22, 29 in Dec is sunday, i want display in xaxis label.
- with days 16, 30 in Dec, i dont want display in xaxis, but in yaxis should be display point label.

My problem i cant find how to do that, anyone can suggest me anyway.
Thank

Answer (score 0):

You have to define min and max value

```
axes: {
       // Use a category axis on the x axis and use our custom ticks.
       xaxis: {
         min : 15,
         max : 29,
         numberTicks:3
       }
}
```